# Abbreviation for "Ignore any trivial solutions"

Tags: combinatorics

Frequently, I'll have a really nice problem expressible in just a few words, but then I have to carefully rule out the trivial cases. Often, ruling out the trivial uses more words than the rest of the problem statement.  Even then, people will bring up the trivial cases.

Is there a nice short word or abbreviation that brushes away any consideration for the trivial cases?

Comment: You should probably rule out the trivial cases, rather than the non-trivial ones.

Comment: A couple examples please?

Comment: I would suggest not using an abbreviation.  I think it is important to state exactly what *trivial* means to you.  For example, if the question was "Are there any integers $x,y,z,n$ such that $x^n+y^n=z^n$?," is $x=y=z=0$ trivial?  Is $n=2$ trivial?

Comment: Why would anyone consider using such an abbreviation? :-|

Answer (score 0):

The Riemann hypothesis concerns nontrivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function. Usually you just describe the solutions in which you are interested as "nontrivial," and of course what that means, and how clear it is, is up to the context.

Other times you just need to fess up and state your hypothesis. "For all $x \neq 0$", "for all primes $p > 2$", etc., are totally clear ways of communicating.